# ArcGIS 10.2 arcpy -- how to import/install win32com?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, installation, excel

win32com used to be included with arcpy 9.x but no longer.  I used to use it to manipulate excel occasionally.

I downloaded and let win32com install itself and then tried to follow some online instructions for moving the win32com api to its own win32com directory in ArcGISx6410.2\Lib, but that seemed to have no effect.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It works well for me in 10.1, installed as default, did you get the correct version for your python install?

Comment: I just got it working, but I had to move all of the contents (pyd's) of Lib\win32 and Lib\win32\lib out to the site-packages level.  Now it can find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it working, but I had to move all of the contents (pyd's) of Lib\win32 and Lib\win32\lib out to the site-packages level. Now it can find them, but it's sort of an ad hoc solution.